# How to manually call form validations before submitting form using jQuery in mvc2

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, form-submit

Im using mvc 2, my view is as follows

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ApplyLeave", "ESS", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formApplyLeave" }))
       { %>
    <fieldset>            
        <div>
            <div>
                <label for="FromDate">
                    From</label></div>
            <div>
                <%=Html.TextBoxFor(l => l.FromDate, new { id = "FromDate", name = "FromDate", maxlength = 10 })%>
            </div>
            <div>
                <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(l => l.FromDate)%></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <label for="ToDate">
                    To</label></div>
            <div>
                <%=Html.TextBoxFor(l => l.ToDate, new { id = "ToDate", name = "ToDate", maxlength = 10 })%>
            </div>
            <div>
                <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(l => l.ToDate)%></div>
        </div>            
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>
```

and for submitting the form, im using jquery as

```
       $('#formApplyLeave').submit();
```

I wrote the validation in attributes in model.

Here im able to submit the form, but validation are not getting fired. How do i fire the validations in jquery, before submitting the form.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [beforeSubmit](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object) callback to set values:

**Or** using jQuery validation plug-in's validate method

try like this~

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function() {
        $("#txt1").val("123");

        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                    txt1: {
                            maxlength: 3
                    }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This way validation will be triggered by your submit event handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
var form = $('#formApplyLeave');
var context = Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm(form.get(0));
if (context.validate().length < 1) {
    // The form passed client side validation => you may submit it
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ScottGu has a good article that describes what you need:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

You're missing a call and some MS JS.